# Image not load in Google map marker

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, picasso, firebase-storage

I am trying to load image in Google map that I have fetched from Firebase Storage in marker window. The thing is, when I try to load it with Glide or Picasso, it's not loading in Google map. Every log I have in the code is visible in logcat. Am I doing something wrong here?

Here is my code

```
public class MapInfoWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private StorageReference storageReference;
    private Chalet chalet;
    private boolean query;
    private ImageView img;
    private String lat;
    private String log;

    public MapInfoWindowAdapter(Context context, LayoutInflater inflater) {
        this.context = context;
        this.inflater = inflater;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(final Marker marker) {

        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("chalets");
        storageReference=FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.marker_tag,null);

       final LatLng latlng = marker.getPosition();
       Double doubleLat = latlng.latitude;

         lat = String.valueOf(latlng.latitude);
         log = String.valueOf(latlng.longitude);
        Log.i("MarkerPostion",lat);

        img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.chaletImg);

       // final TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.markerText);
        final Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(0);
       mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                Log.i("MarkerPostion","112211");
                for (DataSnapshot snapm: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Log.i("MarkerPostion",snapm.child("latitude").getValue().toString());
                    Log.i("Key",snapm.getKey());
                    if ( lat.equals(snapm.child("latitude").getValue().toString()) && log.equals(snapm.child("longitude").getValue().toString()) ){
                        chalet = snapm.getValue(Chalet.class);
                        Log.i("MarkerPostion","9999");
                        break;
                    }
                }

                storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child(chalet.getOwnerID()).child(chalet.getChaletNm()).child("1");
                storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        Picasso.with(context).load(uri).into(img);
                        Log.i("MarkerPostion","2222");
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });       

        return v;
    }
}
```

Here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/markerFrame">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/chaletImg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
             />

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Could you supply the xml file that you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Map markers are rendered as Bitmaps and are not live Views, which means that by the time Picasso finishes loading the image, you're marker has already been rendered and you need to refresh it to display the changes.

What you need to do is implement a Callback on the, either Picasso, or Glide call and call `marker.showInfoWindow()` once the image is loaded.

**EDIT:**
I think that this is the only change that you need:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(uri).into(img, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                            marker.showInfoWindow()
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError() {

                        }
                    });
```

You could also check `if (marker != null && marker.isInfoWindowShown())` before calling `marker.showInfoWindow()`...

Comment: i have tried your solution and still it doesn't show the image, also your code seems has recursion of some kind.

Comment: Did you try adding the if statement before calling marker.showInfoWindow()?

Comment: Yes, i have also tried to hide it then show but still no image.

Comment: Try to keep a reference to the last selected marker and update that one instead (if you still get the recursive call), when the image loads successfully. Check out this example: https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/MarkerDemoActivity.java#L182

Comment: Thank you, I think this answer is the closest to the solution. what i did is create a boolean variable that if the first time load the image it became true then second time only load from the cache.

Comment: Thanks and glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the `LinearLayout` in your xml the root view of the layout. I never realized why, but I faced problems too when I dealt with a custom `InfoWindowAdapter` without an obvious explanation/bug. Using a `LinearLayout` as root view of the xml solved my issues.

Comment: could you provide me a sample of your code if you don't mind. thx.

Comment: Try this

inline `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/markerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/chaletImg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
             />
    </LinearLayout>`